# Azure website: How to manually import application settings from a file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to import azure web sites application setting from a file.I could not find a direct link from the azure portal.

**Update**

I want to copy some application settings from one azure web site to another azure web site in our test environment. I don't want to automate this, as we have our deployment infrastructure in place. I just want some simple solution where I can export the application settings from one web-site and import to another for testing.

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you want to load settings from a file? Or would you like to export portal settings to a file? For the first one, there's multiple resources available.

Comment: I want to import settings from a file manually not through deployment slots, could not locate any options in the azure portal. Would be a great help if you can point to to it.

Answer (score 3):

> want to copy some application settings from one azure web site to another azure web site in our test environment

If you check the Azure web app in [Azure Resource Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/), you can find **[Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)** info is under **config/web** section, and it provides [an API to update the configuration of an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateconfiguration).

[image]

You can try to get Application settings of one website via Azure Resource Explorer, and then you can call [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateconfiguration) to update another website Application settings. If you save Application settings of one Azure website in a file, you can read file content and construct request based on it and send request to update another website.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload a fresh copy of your web.config, but that'll recycle your app when you do so. That's about the only support out-of-the-box for manually changing settings via a file.

You could also do the following:

1. Create a Settings class that's a singleton and reads settings from a file.
2. Within the Settings class, set up a FileSystemWatcher on the file containing your settings.
3. On the FileSystemWatcher.OnChanged event, re-read your settings file.

Comment: thanks a valid solution for production. But I just want to do this on my test environment and its a one time job something export setting and import setting solution is I am looking for some simple solution for that.

Comment: Are you ok with an app pool recycle? If so, define settings within your web.config's <appSettings></appSettings> block. You can then copy and paste your <appSettings> section between files. You can even do it through a web browser via your Web App's scm site.

Comment: Yes I am fine with app pool recycle as I mentioned this is for test environment. I am using aspnet.core

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Core, why not use the standard appsettings.json solution? See [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration)

Answer (score 0):

As to Azure Portal you can go to Configuration/Application settings and open Advanced edit where you can paste JSON version of the settings. You need to do it separately for Connection strings. (If you already have settings in Azure then you can copy them from there - what would be an export in that case).

[image]

Connection strings

[image]